# Deploying Django With AWS

Tags: python, django, git, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

So I am trying to **deploy** my **django** app(which mostly has REST Apis) but when I use Amazon CLI, I end up having **Fedora instance**, while I **want** to use **Ubuntu instance**.

So I tried to do this, I made an ubuntu instance, made a repository of my code, installed git on ubuntu and cloned the code from git to ubuntu. Next thing, I installed all the requirements.txt dependencies and everything is in virtualenv and working fine.

But here's the **catch**, `python manage.py runserver` runs it on `localhost`(not really surprising). So the question is, how to serve those apis(not on localhost)?

Comment: Have you not read any of the extremely comprehensive docs on deployment? There is no way you would **ever** want to use runserver in a deployment scenario.

Comment: You get Fedora instead of Ubuntu because you are not picking the right AMI. The official Ubuntu AMIs can be found here https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=565feec9-3d43-413e-9760-c651546613f2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `runserver` command on production. It's meant for local development only.

On production, you need to setup an application server (uwsgi / gunicorn) and then use nginx as a reverse proxy.

Digital Ocean articles are pretty good - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04

(The same stuff apply for AWS as well)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, `runserver` command is only meant for local development. You can, in fact, make it listen on external interfaces by running it as `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, but it is a bad idea. Configuring nginx+uwsgi to run a Django app is very easy. There are multiple tutorials and guides available for this. Here is the official uWSGI guide
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT use django development server in production. It is not built for that use.

Instead use something like elastic beanstalk that'll help you deploy out of box scalable django apps. Here's a good step-by-step tutorial for that: https://www.trysudo.com/deploying-django-app-on-aws-using-elastic-beanstalk/